# Use ts for tsx react files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Is it possible to use `.ts` extensions for React typescript `.tsx` files without the IDE and the compiler going crazy?

Comment: Yes. File extensions can be configured in `tsconfig`. You can list the files explicitly or use an `include` regexp. What's the IDE? All IDE's that I know of allow you to configure them to use whichever language for whichever file type.

Comment: Why do you want to write JSX in `.ts` files?

Comment: Late to the party. One of the use case I had was, Refactoring hyperscript based code into JSX. All my files are named .view.ts . If I could configure that all .view.ts files to be treated as tsx that would have been great. This would have helped my by not renaming to tsx losing all the history of original file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Right now, no. There are technical reasons for the existence of the `.tsx` extension.

There is an ambiguity that JSX introduces when it comes to TypeScript's original type assertion syntax - specifically, it's not clear if `<Foo>xyz` is the start of a JSX tag or a type assertion. That's why we had to adopt the `as` type assertion syntax (i.e. `xyz as Foo`) and introduce the `.tsx` file extension.

Even aside from that, supporting JSX means that TypeScript has to decide on how to disambiguate something like a generic arrow function. For example, in this case

```
let identity = <T>(x: T) => x
```

TypeScript parses that as the start of a JSX tag. Users have to turn this into a non-ambiguous form to get the equivalent code:

```
let identity = <T extends {}>(x: T) => x
```

In short: supporting JSX would have implied breaking changes or a whole lot of unnecessary complexity in the compiler with worse error recovery for JSX.

Comment: This answer is from 2016. Is it still the case today?

Comment: Yes, or is still the case today, and probably will be indefinitely.

Answer (score 1):

With Babel you can use this switch:

https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-typescript#istsx

we should use the new type assertion syntax everywhere anyway...